# Magento 2 custom javascript for theme

Tags: magento2, javascript

Im trying to add custom JS in my new theme. 
I managed to add custom css in `default_head_blocks.xml`
Like this:

```
<css src="css/customtheme.css" />
<css src="css/styles-m.css" />
<css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
<css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
```

Now i tried to do the same with **javascript**:

```
<script src="js/javascript.js" />
```

To test it i added this code in **js/javascript.js**:

```
alert('test!');
```

But sadly nothing. What is the corrrect way to include javascript in a custom **magento 2 theme**?

Thanks in advance,

-Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **link**

```
    <link src="js/javascript.js" />
```

Comment: Nothing still for some reason :l

Comment: did you deploy the content after that `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I had to deploy it